tf.keras.models.load_model fail to load a model that was saved with tf.keras.models.save_model
I'm trying to load a previously trained model but it gives me this error. Is there any way I can convert this file format to the new format or how do I fix this? I'd rather not have to train a new model if possible.
#Model was previously saved with     
tf.keras.models.save_model(file_path)
#Load back in (causes error)
model_a = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_path)

This is the error received:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-120117fe47ab> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #@title Load the checkpoint
      2 checkpoint_path = '/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2' # @param {type:"string"}
----> 3 model_a = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_path)
      4 tf.keras.utils.plot_model(ad._model, show_shapes = True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    197         )
    198     else:
--> 199         raise ValueError(
    200             f"File format not supported: filepath={filepath}. "
    201             "Keras 3 only supports V3 `.keras` files and "

ValueError: File format not supported: filepath=/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2. Keras 3 only supports V3 `.keras` files and legacy H5 format files (`.h5` extension). Note that the legacy SavedModel format is not supported by `load_model()` in Keras 3. In order to reload a TensorFlow SavedModel as an inference-only layer in Keras 3, use `keras.layers.TFSMLayer(/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2, call_endpoint='serving_default')` (note that your `call_endpoint` might have a different name).


Leaving this here for people with custom layers in:
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI/final_AI',
                custom_objects={'TransformerBlock': TransformerBlock,
                'TokenAndPositionEmbedding': TokenAndPositionEmbedding, 
                'TransformerDecoder': TransformerDecoder, 
                "weighted_loss": get_weighted_loss},
                 compile=True)
model.load_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI/final_AI_weights')

If you are using or did use Keras 2 in your old project you can fix this by using import tf_keras instead of from tf import keras or import keras.
tf_keras is keras 2.15. If you have custom layers you have to change every tf.keras in your code to tf_keras.
This solution worked for me and my old model now runs as it used to.
You can find the information on the official keras webpage: https://keras.io/keras_3/ under "Moving from Keras 2 to Keras 3"

Looks like checkpoint_path variable you're using to load your keras model doesn't have an extension. From the documentation, load_model filepath argument has to have .keras extension that isn't included in the file when you call save_model it so load_model couldn't determine if the file is in .keras or .h5 format. To fix the problem you just need to add the .keras file extension when saving the model
If 2 is a directory
import os
checkpoint_path = '/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2'
model_filepath = os.path.join(checkpoint_path, 'model.keras')
#Model was previously saved with     
tf.keras.models.save_model(model_filepath)
#Load back in (causes error)
model_a = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_filepath)

If 2 is a intended filename for the model
import os
checkpoint_path = '/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2.keras'
#Model was previously saved with     
tf.keras.models.save_model(file_path)
#Load back in (causes error)
model_a = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_path)

Edit: from your comment, it looks like you're using SavedModel format hence there were .pb files with assets and variables folder. If that's the case, then you should use tf.keras.model.load_model function instead and add the directory of the saved model as argument
import tensorflow as tf
checkpoint_path = '/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2'
model.save(checkpoint_path)
model_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_path)


So previously, when I trained and saved the model (a couple months ago), I only had to indicate a file path and it saved into that folder these files: "keras_metadata.pb", "fingerprint.pb", "saved_model.pb" and 2 empty folders called "assets" and "variables." At the time, all I had to do was indicate the filepath and it would load the  model. Now, I tried adding the ".keras" extension to the end of my filepath and got file not found error: "File not found: filepath=/drive/MyDrive/dummy/2.keras. Please ensure the file is an accessible .keras zip file." Please help.

@BiBi Oh I see, looks like the model you're using is SavedModel. Just want to confirm, did you check the directory path at /drive/MyDrive/dummy/2 on your file explorer that is where the .pb files and assets and variables folder are saved? I think the reason it's returning that error is could that directory on your file system doesn't have those files, make sure you enter the right file path

I made sure it had the files, I think there's a new update and Keras load_model cannot load SavedModel anymore. I had to load it as a TFSMLayer instead. Thank you for your help.
